# Place UIPickerView in the centre of the UIAlertController

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uipickerview, uialertcontroller

How I can place **UIPickerView** in the centre of the **UIAlertController**?

Now I have this code:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Представьтесь пожалуйста", message: "Кто вы?", preferredStyle: .alert)
alertController.isModalInPopover = true
userTypePickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                                y: 0,
                                                width: alertController.view.bounds.size.width,
                                                height: 140))
userTypePickerView.delegate = self
userTypePickerView.dataSource = self
let height: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertController.view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 240)
alertController.view.addConstraint(height)
alertController.view.addSubview(userTypePickerView)
```

And i see this picture...

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that. From docs: `Important
The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.`

Comment: But it can be do it, bit i don't know how :(

Comment: @ДмитрийДеникаев it can be done but as @Desdenova said don't do it because you may have problems in future iOS updates if Apple decides to change view hierarchy of `UIAlertController`. Create custom alert for this instead.

Comment: @NajdanTomić hmm, this is true, thank you, and I will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite i vote for creating a custom alert , but you can do this

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Представьтесь пожалуйста", message: "Кто вы?", preferredStyle: .alert)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
alertController.isModalInPopover = true
let userTypePickerView = UIPickerView(frame:.zero)
 alertController.view.addSubview(userTypePickerView)
userTypePickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    userTypePickerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
    userTypePickerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
    userTypePickerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alertController.view.topAnchor,constant:70),
    userTypePickerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alertController.view.bottomAnchor,constant:-40),
    userTypePickerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alertController.view.centerXAnchor)
])
userTypePickerView.backgroundColor = .red
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I think you forgot `userTypePickerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: alertController.view.centerYAnchor`, I added in my code this line and it help me. Thanks.